# Passing Quotation Mark Character (") as C# Console Application Argument

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a project to demonstrate a program similar to the "echo" command in the MS-DOS Command Line. Here is the code in C#:

```
using System;

namespace arguments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                switch (args[0])
                {
                    case "/?":
                        string location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
                        string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(location);
                        Console.WriteLine("Displays messages\nSyntax: {0} [message]", name);
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                        break;
                }
                if (args.Length >= 0)
                {
                    string x = "";
                    foreach (var item in args)
                    {
                        x += item.ToString() + " ";
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(x)); // this should eliminate vulnerabilities.
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                string location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
                string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(location);
                Console.WriteLine("Displays messages\nSyntax: {0} [message]", name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does a pretty efficient job at doing what it's supposed to do. Then I got into trying to exploit it in any way I could.

In command prompt, I ran `arguments.exe "`, this is supposed to print out `"`. But that's not really what happened. I then tried the same with the `echo` command by running `echo "`, and it, like it's supposed to, printed out `"`. This is mind boggling because I wouldn't have even thought this would be a problem. I couldn't get it to pose a great threat, just confused me for a minute.

My question is, is there any way to pass the quotation mark (`"`) as argument to this console application?

Here is a picture to demonstrate it a little bit better: http://prntscr.com/cm9yal

Comment: Hello Black VikingPro... I am not sure why it would print a " character. As command line arguments the " character signals the beginning of a string and the next one signals the end of the string, if you want to print the " character you need to put \ character in from of it. if you supply echo \" it will print out echo "... i think its the " character that is used to enclose strings in command line arguments.

Comment: @JohnG You are right. Your point is valid in Unix. However, I also discovered that given only one quotation mark as argument, the Windows `echo` command strangely just prints that quotation mark out! You may try it yourself.

Comment: @ BlackVikingPro    I get the impression that you think you are actually "executing" the echo command... and this is not what is happening here... you are just printing out the command... not executing it

Comment: @BlackVikingPro   When i supply echo as the argument... it prints echo

Comment: @JohnG look at the screenshot, he's using the DOS echo command. I've had a look and can confirm that `"` is not passed to the executing process, either as args, nor is it available in `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs`. I would summise that it's a feature of the CLR to perform some rudimentary parsing of the args, but I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: @Smudge202 I can not argue there... his output is different than mine. I just don't see in his code where he actually "executes" the command. Obviously I am missing something and will refrain from further comment.

Comment: @Smudge202 I want to clean the user input as well as I can. It's not specifically just passing the double quotation marks as a string. It's about closing up all vulnerabilities. Such as you would go `$clean_input = htmlspecialchars($raw_input);` in PHP. I need a similar thing in C#

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "vulnerabilities". You're simply printing out text; what is it you're trying to protect against? (I'm afraid I don't know PHP at all so your reference is a little difficult for me to follow)

Comment: security threats, are there any vulnerabilities in my code that can be exploited? Such as XSS or code exploitation?

Comment: your comments don't make any sense.  what does XSS have to do with a console application?

Comment: As @Claies mentioned, this isn't the web so there is no need to sanitise the argument, given your usage of that argument. So long as you're only passing that argument to `Console.WriteLine` or similar, there is no vulnerability there. It is not possible for this type of input to "escape" from a code block and execute malicious code.

Comment: @Smudge202 and Claies I see what you guys mean now, I'm sorry, I'm not too familiar with C# as I just started studying it. I just wanted to know about vulnerabilities on this issue I was having. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Main(string[] args)
```

`args` array here contains the arguments which have been passed to your application. Because arguments may have spaces they can be surrounded by quotes.

For this reason you won't get the string you have placed as argument. You will also loose any number of spaces between quoted parameters.

If you need the raw command line string, use:

```
string cmdline = System.Environment.CommandLine;
```

Comment: This is fine, though it prints out the filename with the message, making my argument **/?** useless. How to I fix this?

Comment: just "cut" the filename from the string representing the command line. For example with cmdline = cmdline.substring( System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.length). By the way: take care to first check if you are passing any parameters at all, otherwise your switch statement will throw an exception because you are accessing the first argument via args[0] without having any argument specified.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to get the single quote, you'll need to bypass the default parsing performed by the CLR when populating the args array. You can do this by examining `Environment.CommandLine`, which in the case you describe above will return something along the lines of:

`ConsoleApplication1.exe  \"`

Note, the argument I passed was simply `"` (not the escaped variant shown).

Comment: `\"` is a single quote, it's just how it's shown in the debugger. If you print that string, you'll see only `"`